# Exploring if headcount in servicedesk does have an impact on resolution time - multiple linear regression?

Tags: regression, independence

I would like to check with you if my issue can be solved by statistics and multiple linear regression? I have data from servicedesk about issues reported in last 2 years. I got a task to prepare a tool to do what-if forecast - management wants to know if they change headcount resolution time will also change. My idea is to do regression with various variables - from the data I have I decided that following things could have an impact on average time to resolve:

how many people resolved incidents in certain period of time (I don't have any HR data, I can only base on issue data I have)

how many incidents were closed

how many people issue tickets in time

how many new tickets come in time

My plan was to check if there is a correlation between those variables and if yes calculate a reggresion function and then create a tool in PowerBi that can allow to management to insert a field with e.g. number of employees that is 20% higher that curretn and check if average time is shorter and if they want to hire additiona people.

Is this approach a good one? Should I pay attention to something? Have you heard about similar example/case study that I could read to try to use in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to give you a definite answer without seeing the data you work with. But here is an example using R of how I would start.

I generate some data to work with. I assume that in different time periods `t` there are a different number of people working at the service desk:

```
set.seed(100)
t <- c(1:10)
headcount <- round(runif(length(t), min = 5, max = 15))
plot(t, headcount)
```

[image: plot1]

So in period 1 and 2 there are 8 people working there, in period 3 there are 11 people working there and so on. Then I assume, that more people are able to close more tickets in one period:

```
closed_tickets <- round(rnorm(length(t), mean = headcount, sd = 2))
plot(headcount, closed_tickets)
```

[image: plot2]

You can see, the higher the headcount on the x-axis, the higher the number of closed tickets on the y-axis. To formalize that even further, you can fit a regression model on the data:

```
reg <- lm(closed_tickets~headcount)
reg
```

which yields that the intercept is `-2.106` and the coefficient for headcount is `1.218`, meaning for every additional person, the number of closed tickets in a period increases by `1.218`. You can also visualize this:

```
plot(headcount, closed_tickets)
abline(reg$coefficients[1], reg$coefficients[2])
```

[image: plot3]

This is only a start and does not take into consideration the other variables you mentioned. By taking the other variables into the regression model as well, you get a multiple linear regression. The basics are the same, you just can't visualize it as easily anymore.